# Looking for feedback on matching and difference-in-differences analysis

Tags: difference-in-difference, matching

I am looking to set up my data and I have a question about the matched-pairs approach. I have plans for how to setup my data and am hoping for feedback as to whether it is a good way to go.

Essentially, I have counties that are observed weekly over the course of a year. Some of them experience a treatment and some do not (of course). The treatment is time-varying. In each time period a focal county experiences the treatment, I am trying to set up my data so that I have a pool of controls cases that I can pull from to match on at each time point. I am thinking my goal would be to setup different time intervals so that I can look at the treated cases anywhere from 1-5 weeks pre/post the treatment and with the untreated cases also matched up to the treated cases so that I am observing them anywhere from 1-5 weeks pre/post the 'non-treatment' My question are:

(1) Am I thinking about this correctly?

(2) Would it make sense to structure each time period separately (e.g.,, one time period consists of all treated cases at week 10 observed 1-5 weeks pre/post along with all possible control cases at week 10 observed 1-5 weeks pre/post) and then repeat the process and stack it with the other time periods later on (i.e., those that experienced the treatment in week 11, week 12, and so on)?

(3) does it matter if a control case has overlapping times for which it's serving as a control? For example, can case B be a control for case A that was treated in week 10 and also a control for case C that was treated in 11?

(4) when matching between treated and untreated cases, do you set the time period to be an exact match such that treated cases can only match with cases that share the characteristics that are being matched on during the time period of interest?

Lastly, I am thinking I would use this data set up, use CEM to pair the treated and untreated cases, and then proceed with my DiD analysis. Also, I understand there may be other ways to setup in the DiD for my data, perhaps such as the generalised DiD, but is my approach valid as well?

Feedback would be much appreciated.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you considered a synthetic cohort approach?

Comment: Also, cross-posted [at Statalist](https://www.statalist.org/forums/forum/general-stata-discussion/general/1556360-question-about-setting-up-my-data-for-matching-and-did-analysis).

Comment: @DimitriyV.Masterov   Thanks Dimitriy. I'll make sure to note cross-posts in the future. My understanding of the synth approach is that it is useful if you only have one treated entity (e.g., Abadie et al. 2010), so I hadn't given it much thought. I have multiple entities that experience treatment events over time. As far as the approach I suggest above, is my thinking coherent in terms of the setup I'm envisioning? Thank you.

Comment: There are generalizations of the approach to multiple treated units which can be treated at different times. See `synth_runner` in Stata and `SCtools` or `microsynth` in R. There may be other implementations that I am not aware of.

Comment: This looks like a job for marginal structural models for time-vary treatments. Check out Robins, Hernán, and Brumback (2000) for an introduction. This method uses weighting instead of matching to create balance at each time point.